# How to disable the button unless checkbox is not checked in ionic

Tags: checkbox, ionic-framework

The following is my code

```html
    <li class="item item-checkbox  checkbox-assertive">I have read and agree to abide by the<br/> <a ng-click="showPopup()">terms and conditions</a>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"  name="accept" required>
        </label>
    </li>

    <a ng-href="#/search/{{select.mySelect}}/{{select.mySelect1}}" id="bloodBankIndia-button1" class=" button button-assertive  button-block icon-left ion-ios-search " ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form1.$invalid">Search</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Anchor tags can't be disabled and buttons can be. In ionic-framework you can use `ui-sref` attribute for navigating pages. Set `ui-sref` for buttons and disable them.

Answer (score 0):

For TOS you can use something like this:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) { return true; } else { alert('Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions'); return false; }">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

P.S. [Disabled is not a valid attribute for the anchor tag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

---

If you want to use ui-sref, as [Harish Kommuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5725554/harish-kommuri) mentioned above in the comments, you can make [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28973586/5059916).