# Can't disable links on invalid form sections in a multi-step form created using Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multistep form with nested views(the views load without page reload), but the problem is that ng-disabled is not working on links. Even though the form is invalid, the link upon clicking loads next view.

Here's one of the views.

```
<div id="wrapper-signup">
  <h1>Borrower Signup</h1>
  <p>Register and start borrowing money online.</p>

  <div class="element-wrap">
    <label>NAME<br>
      <div class="name-wrap">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.lastname" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </label><br>
  </div>
  <div class="element-wrap">
      <label for="email">EMAIL
        <div class="email-num-wrap">
          <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg email-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><input type="email" id="email" ng-model="newuser.email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email ID" required>
        </div>
        <p class="error" style="color: red; font-size: 0.8em;" ng-show="signForm.email.$invalid && signForm.email.$dirty">Enter a valid email</p>
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="element-wrap">
    <label>MOBILE NUMBER
      <div class="email-num-wrap">
        <span><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x mobile-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><input type="number" id="number" ng-model="newuser.number" name="mobile-number" value="" placeholder="Enter 10 digit number">
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="clear">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="terms" value="" required><p class="checkbox-text">I have read and agree to the <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> and consent to Electronic Disclosures.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="condiiton" value="" required><p class="checkbox-text">I authorize RupaiyaExchange to share my details with other Financial Institutions for credit card check and faster processing of loan.</p>
  </div>
  <a ui-sref='index.otp' ng-disabled="signForm.email.$invalid" class="submit-signup">SIGNUP</a>

</div>
```

Comment: There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks. Use button instead.

Comment: here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479105/angularjs-ng-disabled-not-working-for-anchor-tag       and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973530/disable-ui-sref-based-on-a-condition

Comment: If you really need to use an `<a>` element, this might work as well ► `ng:class="{true:'noPointerEvent', false:''}[signForm.email.$invalid]"` with css `.noPointerEvent{pointer-events: none;}` and if you want to make the link look disabled you can add color/background-color as needed to the class. - In IE though it won't work below IE11 though

Comment: @digit thank you, I didn't know that. now I am using ng-show instead, but thank you for the links.

I have another situation, which is that the input data from different views is not getting stored.

I'll post another question for it.